# data.table - fread() select argument

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I want to import a single column from a large, 25 column text file. I am using fread() from the data.table package with the argument 'select = 1'. To avoid crashing the program, I would like to know if fread() loads the text file in its entirety and then subsets the chosen column or does it read only the single column?

Example:

```
df.CustID.fread = fread(input = paste(path, file.name[1], sep = ""),
                            na.strings = c("NA", ""), select = 1)
```

Comment: Looking at the soruce code for `fread` on GitHub it seems like it is read entirely first and then reordered/subsetted (https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/fread.R see line 125 ff.)

Comment: It looks like your right. thanks for pointing that out!